# What is the importance of trees in Prisoners?

Tags: analysis, prisoners

Throughout *Prisoners*, different shots of different trees are shown (including the famous tree shot at the beginning) and after searching for some time about what do they really mean I only found [this](https://www.indiewire.com/2013/12/prisoners-director-denis-villeneuves-discusses-our-best-shot-of-the-year-90684/) article which is based on one of director's interviews.

> They’re kind of like ghost characters.
>
> They’re always there, at least in the background. Each scene you can
> feel their presence. And they are linked with this idea of necessary
> violence.

However, the scene that raises my curiosity is the scene with a tree that looks a lot like "tree of life" and given the many uses of symbolism in this movie and having Roger Deakins at there hands, I wonder if there are other meanings/symbols behind the trees.